# Site for learning about video codecs on the web

Tags: video, h.264, mpeg, html5

I am interested in learning about the HTML 5 specification as well as different video codecs for use in various browsers (mobile and desktop). So In an effort to learn about as much as I can, I'm starting this post. Please feel free to give any resources you found helpful in this regard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](http://web.archive.org/web/20110726002026/http://diveintohtml5.org/video.html) a good one I've been reading. Very in-depth coverage of video and audio codecs/ file formats, and how they relate to the web.